# Emacs color syntax configuration

Tags: eclipse, emacs

Does anyone know if I can find an emacs color syntax configuration which resembles eclipse's syntax coloring? Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what Eclipse looks like, but you might want to check out [Color Theme](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme) There are lots of color themes included with it and you can easily create you own if you don't like any you see.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want **font-lock**.  The emacs name for syntax coloring.  I get it with the mode (Java mode, C# mode, cc-mode, etc).

I have in my .emacs:

```
;; for fontification in emacs progmodes:
(load "font-lock")
(setq font-lock-maximum-decoration t)
;; turn on font-lock globally
(global-font-lock-mode 1  'ON)
```

And then it just works, for all the various prog modes.

[Emacs with C# http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6be39f23a3.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6be39f23a3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this... http://jasonm23.github.com/emacs-theme-editor/

It will customize most of the standard font-lock parameters (keywords, functions, constants, vars, etc....)

You can paste in an existing theme and edit it, if you have something almost right.

There's a few samples on http://jasonm23.github.com

You might also like the code theme generator at http://inspiration.sweyla.com/code/

Answer (score 0):

I use the same .xemacs/init.el file for both Emacs and Xemacs.
In order for it to work, I use the following:

```
; turn on faces
(font-lock-mode 1)

;; Turn on font-lock mode for Emacs
(cond ((not running-xemacs)
   (global-font-lock-mode t)
))
```

Also you might need to add modes for various files.  For example:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (mapcar 'purecopy
                          '(("\\.c$" .    c-mode)
                            ("\\.cc$" .   c-mode)
                            ("\\.cxx$" .  c++-mode)
                            ("\\.htm$" .  html-mode)
                            ("\\.java$" . java-mode))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note there is also a Go mode for emacs which supports color highlighting. [URL for Go-mode for Emacs](https://github.com/dominikh/go-mode.el)